# clear contents of range except selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range, col 1 is a number (£), col 2 is a date and cols 3 to 7 are numbers again. Usually there are about 20 rows in the range. If I enter a value in column 1 of the range i want to clear all the other contents of col 1 from top to bottom but leave the last value entered. I then want to use the position of the value left in col 1 to start a sumif etc in col 3 - 7 from that position downwards to the end of the range.
What I am doing is entering my bank balance as at today's date in col 1, then doing various sums etc on col 3 - 7 to see how poor I will be at the end of the month based on today's (sometimes negative) balance!
Thanks in advance, David

Comment: What does your code look like currently?

Comment: Please share your code for more clarity.

Comment: I have tried it with formula but I am not experienced enough to use VBA. I tried various things life OFFSET with COUNTIF but got into a mess.

Comment: Looks easier to do with formulas at a glance. 

If you need VBA the best chance of a response is with some existing code and the specific bug in that code to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've sorted it with a combination of VBA and formula. The VBA finds the current position in the range H11 - H30 and holds it for me as this is my starting point for the sums in 3 of the other columns.

```
If Target.Row < Range("$H$11").Row Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column < Range("$H$11").Column Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row > Range("$H$30").Row Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column > Range("$H$30").Column Then Exit Sub

Range("C41").Value = ActiveCell.Row
```

I now need to sum down to each row, I start at the top and sum down to the row in C41 (balance as at now), incrementing ROW as it goes down the range i.e taking my current bank balance H&(C41), adding the credits, subtracting the debits and giving me a running balance.

=IF($H12<>"",INDIRECT("$H"&$C$41)-SUM(INDIRECT("$K$11"&":"&"$K"&ROW()))+SUM(INDIRECT("$L12"&":$L"&ROW())),$O11+$L12-$K12)

However, this still does not help with the original problem. When I enter my bank balance, say at row H15, I then have to press return and go back up one row to set C41 correctly. Also, cosmetically, I don't want any other figures remaining in H11 - H30 except the one just entered at H15. It would be great to remember C41 somewhere in the code and retrieve it in the formula - putting it in a cell and then reading it back seems a bit naff to me!